# How do I make the images NOT overlap each other with other content when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css

When I resize the browser, the images overlap with the video, and I don't want the to overlap. I want them to stay in position when I resize the browser.

```css
iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;

}

.png1 img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -430px 210px 850px;
}

.png2 img{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -85.100em;
    right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
    <iframe width="600" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c9Qg7vm0lSk" frameborder="0" fullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
     <div class="png1">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gameartpartnersimagehost/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Adventure-Boy-Featured-Game-Art.png">
      </div>
     <div class="png2">
       <img src="http://gameartpartnersimagehost.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/royalty-free-game-art-commando-thumbnail0003.png">
       </div>
```

Comment: They're overlapping because you're using negative margins. Use an alternative way to lay-out your content instead of negative margins.

Comment: why don't you use absolute position in the place of minus margin.

Comment: I have the negatives because I got a nav bar and in top of the video I got another png the negatives just moved the png up so that's why I had negatives

Answer (score 0):

Because for `.png1 img` you are using margin as negetive values and for `.png2 img` you are using `top` value `relativly` to that image.Try removing those properties , you will get line by line

```
iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    max-width: 100%;

}
.video,.png2,.png1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.png1 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.png2 img{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: So i removed the negative values and the top value, then how would I have the two `.png img' next to the video? the only way I can get them next to each other is by using negative values

Comment: did not work the video is no longer centered its on the left one image is next to the video and the other is at the bottom. I need one image on the right and the other on the left and the video centered in between both  in the same line

Answer (score 0):

You should learn [Media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) as well, it will be helpful. Resize window to see the image move down.

**Desktop**

[image]

**Mobile**

[image]

```css
.col {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 46%;
}

.one {
  background-color: none;
}

.two {
  background-color: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="video">
      <iframe width="600" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c9Qg7vm0lSk" frameborder="0" fullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col one">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gameartpartnersimagehost/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Adventure-Boy-Featured-Game-Art.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col two">
      <img src="http://gameartpartnersimagehost.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/royalty-free-game-art-commando-thumbnail0003.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```